# Does there exist a UFD having only finitely many irreducibles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Does there exist a UFD (which is not a field) having only finitely many irreducible elements?

Definition of a UFD is: $R$ is an integral domain ($R$ is a commutative ring having unity and no zero-divisors) such that each $a\in R \setminus (R^* \cup {0})$ factors into a product of irreducible elements.

I've tried to look for one, but without luck so far.

Comment: Nice question. None spring to mind immediately. (You forgot the word "uniquely" in your definition btw).

Answer (score 7):

If you localize $\mathbb Z$ at the multiplicative set $S=\mathbb Z-\bigcup_{i=1}^n p_i\mathbb Z$, where $p_i$ are distinct primes, then you get a UFD having exactly $n$ prime elements.

**Edit.** (To answer some questions raised in the comments.)

> There are no UFDs (excepting fields) having only finitely many *distinct* primes.

First notice that such a ring has finutely many units. Say $q_1,\dots,q_m$ are all primes. Set $a=q_1\cdots q_m$ and consider $a+1,a^2+1,\dots$. Since all these elements are invertible there exist $i\ne j$ such that $a^i=a^j$, a contradiction.

As a side note, a UFD having finitely many primes is necessarily a PID.

Comment: I'm not sure this is precisely true. For example, if you localize $\mathbb{Z}$ away from $(3)$, the ring you get contains infinitely many distinct units, and each of them times $3$ is a distinct irreducible element.

Comment: @exitmouse As far as I know, elements which are associates are considered as not being distinct from arithmetical point of view.

Comment: They are certainly considered distinct elements of the ring. They are just not considered distinct when considering factorizations.

Comment: On the other hand, if the ring has finitely many units and finitely many irreducible elements and all elements factor, then it is finite and thus a field, so no ring with this stricter version of distinctness exists.

Comment: Ah, there's the proof I was looking for! Thank you @TobiasKildetoft.

Comment: There are two questions here, but now we have the answer to both.

Comment: For those not familiar with localization, one can also describe the ring in the answer as consisting of all rationals with numerator not divisible by a fixed finite set of primes.

Comment: @MikeMiller I think this is mainly the name when the ring is not assumed to be commutative from the start (since in this case, it is a very easy statement compared to the version without commutativity from the start).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You're right. Deleted.

Comment: Your edit forgot to include the stipulation there be finitely many units. Also it should be pointed out that prime $\Leftrightarrow$ irreducible in the case of localizations of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @whacka Since a prime times a unit is still a prime it follows from the hypothesis that the ring has finitely many units. The localization of any UFD is also a UFD, but if you like one can point out what you said.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ localized at $(2)$ has only one prime, but infinitely many units. Am I misunderstanding you? As for prime/irreducible, I was thinking that someone who is seeing a localization here for the first time may not even know these are generally distinct ideas, let alone notice you swapped them or why we're allowed to swap them in your example.

Comment: @whacka If you read the previous comments can see that some people thought that such a localization has infinitely many primes.

Comment: Ah, duh, we're not counting primes up to associates, sorry.

Comment: Dear @user26857, in your answer, does the term "distinct primes" mean "non-associate primes"?

Comment: @Arrow Right...